# multiple initial catalog by user choose in c#

Tags: c#, sql, function, parameters

i got 3 databases(MAMAMB2013,MAMAMB2014,MAMAMB2015) on the same server,and one sql scalar function which is take 2 parameters(stock and orders). My function has written in the server MAMAMB2015. I want to do add other databases as parameter for the user check the stock and orders for 2013 and 2014. But my initial catalog is defined for MAMAMB2015.

```
SqlConnection Conn = GetConn("Data Source=200.200.200.11;Initial Catalog=MAMAMB2015;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=19700802;");
```

How can i add initial catalog as parameter for the check all the stock and orders in the all servers by user choose

Regards!

Comment: No, you will have to create two SqlConnections

Comment: is that will be enough for the chack 2013 and 2014 couse my function is in the 2015

Comment: sorry I can't quite understand what you're saying, but if you have a stored procedure that needs to be executed on multiple databases, you will have to call through the SqlConnection which is connected to those three databases. i.e. create a new SqlConnection which is connecting to MAMAMB2014 and also create one for MAMAMB2013

Comment: my point is to make initial catalog empty couse i got 3 databases and  want to add initial catalog as parameter.

Comment: No, there's no constructor which can fullfill your need https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx you'll have to create three SqlConnections for that..